# React Router cannot re-render default page after click on the same link

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am very new to React js and trying to create a person website with a side navigation (about, education... and blogs), when I click on blogs (/blogs) it will show a list of blogs I posted and go to blog details page when I click on the blog title. My issue right now is I can see the list of blogs when I click on Blogs on the side navigation the first time, then if I click on a blog title to see a blog details, I cannot go back to blog list when click on Blogs in side navigation again. I use React Router to navigate among pages.

Below is some of my code. Thanks in advance for your help.
App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/education" component={Education} />
          <Route path="/skills" component={Skills} />
          <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
          <Route path="/blogs" component={Blogs} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
    );
  }
```

Blogs.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router, Switch,
    Route,
  } from "react-router-dom";
import BlogMenu from '../components/BlogMenu';
import Blog1 from './BlogPages/Blog1';
import Blog2 from './BlogPages/Blog2';


class Blogs extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/blogs" exact component={BlogMenu} />
                    <Route path="/blogs/1" component={Blog1} />
                    <Route path="/blogs/2" component={Blog2} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}
    
export default Blogs
```

BlogMenu.js

```
class BlogMenu extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="condiv">
                <h1 className="subtopic">Blogs</h1>
                <ul>
                    <BlogItem title="Blog 1" id="1" />
                    <BlogItem title="Blog 2" id="2" />
                </ul>
            </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

BlogItem.js

```
class BlogItem extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <li className="widecard" id={this.props.id}>
                <Link className="blogtitle" to={`/blogs/${this.props.id}`} >{this.props.title}</Link>
            </li>
            )
        }
    }
```

Blog1.js

```
class Blog1 extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="condiv">
                <h1 className="subtopic">Blog 1 Title</h1>
                <p>Start your Blog1 contents here</p>
            </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: you don't need a nested `<Router>` component. remove that and just have one top level Router that wraps everything

Comment: @azium, thank you! That could resolve my issue, but I also want to know why this nested <Router> does not work. Why the second time when I click on Blogs in side nav, though the url changed to /blogs, it does not render BlogMenu component?

Comment: You only need 1 `Router` for the entire app. It provides the routing context for all `Switch`, `Route`, `Link`, `NavLink`, and `Redirect` components. Each routing/navigation action is handled by the nearest `Router` in the ReactTree, so if you nest them the nested router handles the navigation and any routers higher in the React tree aren't aware of what was handled.

Comment: @DrewReese, Thank you. I removed <Router> from Blogs.js and just keep switch and route, it works fine.